# Remote connection from Navicat to Mysql container

Tags: mysql, containers, localhost, remote-connection

Dudes,
I have a MySQL container on my Windows machine and I want to connect remotely to it from Navicat.
I created a user with global access and a database on the machine as follows:

- username: da_user
- DB: da_DB

I have tried connecting to the machine on many different hosts(below items), but all of them fail.

- Container gateway
- localhost
- 127.0.0.1

Does anyone have a suggestion or know of a solution to fix this issue? Did I miss a step or something?